# Apache Python internal server error 500

Tags: python, html, apache

I have Apache 2.4.6, python 2.7 on rhel 7

I have my html form trial1 as

```
<form action = "/cgi-bin/upload3.py" method = "post">
First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name"><br />
Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name" />

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

I have my python script upload3.py as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')
print "Content-type:text/html"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

I am facing internal server error 500 while passing the form input to python also the error logs are not getting updated.Earlier while it was getting updated it was showing :

```
[Mon Jun 04 19:50:23.883970 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2921] [client 10.19.0.153:63063] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/upload3.py' failed, referer: http://10.210.58.218/trial1.html
[Mon Jun 04 19:50:23.884649 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 2921] [client 10.19.0.153:63063] End of script output before headers: upload3.py, referer: http://10.210.58.218/trial1.html
```

Comment: Can you check the upload3.py file available in the /var/www/cgi-bin/ location?

Comment: I did it is available

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer please run dos2unix command to convert your .py file into a file that does not contain invalid characters.